# How can I put form elements into a table and have a submit at the bottom?

Tags: forms

I'm working on this module and I want it displays a page as follows.

[image: screenshot]

What I am doing to get that is just displaying a table through `theme()` and typing out the HTML for the upload. I want the whole page to be seen as a form; the only element that will need changing is the image that's uploaded. I want also a submit button on the bottom to save changes.

One way to solve this would be to put an edit button and have it go to a new page that is just a form and that would work, but I'd prefer to have it on one page.

What is the best way to do this? Every site I read on is just confusing me more because they are all doing it different; it's not the result I am looking for because not all that is displaying is going to be a form element.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [theme_table](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7).
It will help you.
:)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Bro,this is not an ordinary, it api.drupal.org
if you have any doubt in drupal api, u should search on this. 
whats you need , I am sure this theme_table will resolve your problem.
Please go through the document.

Comment: drupal.stackexchange.com has its own policies to consider something as an ANSWER. Read FAQ http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq please.

Comment: Suggesting to use a theme function doesn't help much. Since the OP wants to theme a form, there is more to do.